Can you use a percentage as the dependent variable in general additive models?
This is more a general question about statistical modeling rather than a project specific question.
Can the dependent variable be a percentage in a generalized additive model (GAM)? Is there a specific basis I need to use for the independent variable if the dependent variable is a percent?

See Percentage as dependent variable in multiple linear regression and others. In general the answer is no, although it may work well enough in certain cases.

That question you link talks about fitting percentages as DVs in MLR, where they provide binomial regression as an alternative. GAMs are equipped to do the same, though I show how to do this with the betar function.

Certainly. Probably the easiest implementation is to use the family = betar() argument, which fits models of proportions that range between zero and one. An example that I have edited from the help page for betar is shown below, which simulates a proportion response, then fits it to a GAM:
#### Load Libraries ####
library(mgcv)

##### Simulate Data ####
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
mu <- binomial()$linkinv(dat$f/4-2)
phi <- .5
a <- mu*phi
b <- phi - a
dat$y <- rbeta(n,a,b) 

#### Visualize Response ####
hist(
  dat$y,
  xlab="Y",
  main="Histogram of Y",
  col="steelblue"
  )

#### Fit Model ####
bm <- gam(
  y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), # TP smooths of x0:x3
  family=betar(link="logit"), # beta family
  data=dat # using this data
  )

#### Plot Fitted Model ####
plot(bm,pages=1)

As you can see here:

Some information about how mgcv achieves this, even with boundary cases (actual zeroes and ones), is detailed here.
As a final note, you mention this in your question:

Is there a specific basis I need to use for the independent variable if the dependent variable is a percent?

This will depend on what you are modeling, but a simple fit would be easily achieved with a cubic regression spline or a thin plate regression spline (using bs = "cr" or bs = "tp" respectively). More advanced fits will depend on what you are doing (such as by-smooths, random effects, etc.).
